# FBDialog orientation issue

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

How can I set the orientation of fblogindialog?  It always appears in portrait mode.  When I set the frames it just becomes in landscape mode but the web view inside the frame doesnt.

What should I do..

Please help here is the code

```
self.loginDialog  = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] init] autorelease];

loginDialog.delegate = self;    
[self.loginDialog show];
//self.loginDialog.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
[self.view addSubview:loginDialog];
```

here is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Yes. I have exactly the same issue. I  am using iOS FB SDK 3.5.2. This is driving me nuts. There must be some kind of argument we can pass in, to tell FB what orientation we want the dialog presented?